# Return value fail

Tags: python-3.x, return-value, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a doubly linked list and I am having trouble getting returning the value I remove an item from the middle of the list. I am not really sure why and would appreciate the a second pair of eyes look this through.

If I append three numbers and then remove the number at index `1,` it should return the value at index `1`.

```
class Linked_List:

    class __Node:

      def __init__(self, val):
          self.val = val
          self.next = None
          self.prev = None
          return


  def __init__(self):
    self.__header = self.__Node(None)
    self.__trailer = self.__Node(None)
    self.__header.next = self.__trailer
    self.__trailer.prev = self.__header
    self.__size = 0


  def __len__(self):
    return self.__size


  def remove_element_at(self, index):
    if index > self.__size or index < 0 or index == self.__size:
       raise IndexError
    cur = self.__header.next
    element_to_return = cur
    if index == 0:
       self.__header.next = self.__header.next.next
    else:
       for i in range(0, index):
          cur = cur.next
       element_to_return = cur.val
       cur.next = cur.next.next
    self.__size -= 1
    return str(element_to_return.val)
```

Comment: `if not (0 <= index < self.__size):` - also  - please show th linked list strucure, what is self.__header.next f.e. or what is self.__header.next.next. DLL normally have a prev (might be None) and a Next (might be None) - removing at X is usually starting at head, going down next until X reached and then modifying prev to point at next, returning the curr.Value. Done

Answer (score 0):

I added the `addValue()` and a `debug()` method (tip: read [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ).

I modified the start/end node to have a value for clarity. I reduced/restructured (rewrote) your  the remove method - it had some unneeded overhead and pointer errors. For double linked lists you have to take care of both the folloing and preceeding element and change all the pointers correctly to keep the integrity of the chain.

```
class Linked_List: 
    class __Node: 
      def __init__(self, val):
          self.val = val
          self.next = None
          self.prev = None
          return 


    def __init__(self):
      self.__header = self.__Node('Start')   # start node
      self.__trailer = self.__Node('End')    # end node
      self.__header.next = self.__trailer 
      self.__trailer.prev = self.__header
      self.__size = 0


    def debug(self):
        cur = self.__header 
        print("prev.val  cur.val  next.val")
        i = 0
        while cur:
            print("  " * i, f'{cur.prev.val if cur.prev else None}  {cur.val}  {cur.next.val if cur.next else None}')
            i+=1
            cur = cur.next


    def addValue(self, val):
        """Adds the str of val at the end."""
        n = self.__Node(str(val))
        n.next = self.__trailer   
        n.prev = self.__trailer.prev
        self.__trailer.prev.next = n
        self.__trailer.prev = n
        self.__size += 1


    def remove_element_at(self, index):
        if not (0 <= index < self.__size ): # simplified
            # better message on error
            raise IndexError (f'Index {index} out of bounds [0,{self.__size-1}]')

        cur = self.__header.next     # simplified, element_to_return not needed

        # there is no need for special cases for 0 or size - this will handle all
        for i in range(0, index):
            cur = cur.next   # go ever deeper, if we are at 0 or self.__size not entering
        cur.prev.next = cur.next  # repointer prev's next to our next
        cur.next.prev = cur.prev  # repointer next's prev to our prev
        self.__size -= 1          # decrease size
        return str(cur.val)       # return our value


k = Linked_List()

for n in range(5):
    k.addValue(n)
k.debug()
removed = k.remove_element_at(4)
k.debug()
print(f'removed: {removed}')
```

Output:

```
prev.val  cur.val  next.val
 None  Start  0
   Start  0  1
     0  1  2
       1  2  3
         2  3  4
           3  4  End
             4  End  None
 None  Start  0
   Start  0  1
     0  1  2
       1  2  3
         2  3  End
           3  End  None
removed: 4
```

Edit:

My add method is self-build. Make sure youres gets the pointers correctly - use the debug method to assure that `cur.prev.next` points to `cur` and `cur.next.prev` is `cur` as well.